# Powershell invoking DTUTIL error

Tags: powershell, octopus-deploy

I'm currently in the process of building a deployment process in octopus deploy and as part of that I want to use DTUTIL to create folders and load SSIS packages to our server. 
This text "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\Binn\dtutil.exe"  /SourceServer [servername] /FC SQL;\;[foldername], with appropriate server and folder names, which works in DOS.

Here is the rub, if I use the same code in Powershell I get an error:

```
$Command ="`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\Binn\dtutil.exe`"  /SourceServer MYSERVER /FC SQL;\;Folder1";
invoke-Expression $Command;
invoke-expression : At line:1 char:73
+ ...  Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\Binn\dtutil.exe"  /SourceSe ...
+                                                                  ~
You must provide a value expression following the '/' operator.
At line:1 char:73
+ ... \Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\Binn\dtutil.exe"  /SourceServer MYSERVER ...
+                                                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token 'SourceServer' in expression or statement.
At line:1 char:1
+ invoke-expression $Command
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [Invoke-Expression], ParseException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExpectedValueExpression,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeExpressionCommand
```

Has anyone got any idea how to remedy this?

Anthony

Comment: If I write the command out to a bat file and then run the bat file the process works, so I will use that method unless someone can help get it working without the extra step.  [IO.File]::WriteAllLines("temp.bat", $command)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can execute the `EXE` using the `&` operator:

```
& "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\Binn\dtutil.exe"  /SourceServer MYSERVER /FC SQL;\;Folder1
```

Also, the above `Invoke-Expression` command failed in the same way when I ran it in PowerShell directly, this doesn't appear to be an issue with running the PowerShell within Octopus.